# Handler fires to early

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an device with an integrated bixolon printer in it. I want to create an app to print on the printer. My OnCreate method looks as follow:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle){
base.OnCreate(bundle);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

printer = new BixolonPrinter(this, new MyHandler(), Looper.MainLooper);
printer.FindUsbPrinters();      

//button connect
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonConnect);
button.Click += delegate {      
    printer.ConnectUsb();//in the brackets I would need the value of the Handler back once it is available
};   }
```

My Handler is as follow:

```
private class MyHandler : Handler
    {
        public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
        {             
            switch (msg.What)
            {
                case BixolonPrinter.MessageUsbDeviceSet:
                    Console.WriteLine("U S B     device::: " + msg.Obj);
                    //can not return the msg.Obj back to the button event
                    break;
            }         
        }
    }
```

The problem is the once the instance of the BixolonPrinter is created it immediately fires the Handler. There is no way to bring back the result of the Handler to the button event. To make that problem a litte bit more complicated, the BixolonPrinter is a Java .jar file. So how can I get the result back to the event button?

Answer (score 0):

When you use MainLooper, everything will be executed on main thread. Create HandlerThread for interaction instead. To postpone execution, use Handler.postDelayed() method, or, what is better, use RxJava library